# Android, If a user delete the SAF tree uri(folder) on SD Card. Couldn't able to create the same folder

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, storage-access-framework

I have fetched the folder uri using SAF Document tree and saved it in Shared Preferences for future files saving purpose. Suppose, If a user delete's the folder. I could create the same folder on sd card.

Alternative:

1) Again ask the user to choose a directory using
   ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE

2) Create a same directory with the deleted folder name - It is not
   working.

Hint:
This is for Android Sdk built version less than 29. Impelemented scoped storage

Pls guide me with apt solution

Answer (score 1):

> > Suppose, If a user delete's the folder. I could create the same folder on sd card.

No you -your app- cant as for that you need saf write permission in parent folder.